# Xcode: lost connection with Error code -1

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This seemingly trivial piece of code is copied from the textbook but after Xcode takes the input at the scanf(), the program exits with error code -1 and says "lost connection".

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

int number;

NSLog(@"Type in your number: ");
scanf("%i", &number);

if (number < 0)
    number = -number;

NSLog(@"The absolute value is: %i", number);
[pool drain];
return 0;

}
```

**Update**

I have reinstalled the OS from scratch. 10.8.5 and Xcode 5 — still the same issue. Installed Xcode 4.6.3, same issue, just no error message, the program just exits.

I also wrote a completely new program in a new blank project. The issue again only exists when the scanf function is called.

Comment: This code works for me when I drop it into an Xcode 5 project.  Which version of Xcode are you using? Are you running the app from Terminal or from within Xcode?

Comment: Xcode 5. Even if I start a new project it doesn't run. Surely it's a config issue then.

Comment: Xcode 5 is still fairly buggy - e.g. often it just can't find the executable file that should be loaded into the Simulator (for iOS Apps). I'd be tempted to say that it's an Xcode issue, not an issue with your code or config.

Comment: Just for giggles, create a new user on your Macintosh (temporarily) and try running your program from that new account.  I suspect your Xcode settings might be messed up.

Comment: New user account didn't work, so it's definitely an OS level issue. I'm going to try and reinstall the OS, if not, I'll format then reinstall.

Comment: Wiped out the computer completely. Installed Xcode 5 and nothing. Very strange. I compiled via Terminal using GCC just fine. Downloaded Xcode 4.6.3 and it just exits the program after I send in the number (no error message though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the program expects an integer value to be inputted, I was hitting the "Enter" key on my keyboard (on the number pad). The scanf method terminates user input after the "Return" key is pressed. Although they are both often referred to as "Enter" keys, they behave very differently in this context.

Also, if you would like to use the "Enter" key, you can add a forward slash to the end of the input and then press "Enter" which would return the same results as the "Return" key.

Silly me.