# Scanf in Objective C Crashes Xcode And the Program

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, crash, scanf

I have removed scanf from the code and the rest of the program runs with no issue. When the code reaches scanf, and after I type a number, xcode 'loses connection' and displays the error "Program ended with exit code: -1". I have also tried making 'input' an int, changed the name of variable input in case there was a conflict there, and tried it without fflush in the code. I am running Mountain Lion on Oracle VM Virtualbox, and my computer is on Windows 7, if that's relevant.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#import Foundation/Foundation.h
#include stdio.h

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])

{

    @autoreleasepool {

        float input = 1;
        int i = 0;
        float total = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int min = 1000;


        while (input != 0){
            NSLog(@"Please put in a number. \n");
            scanf("%f", &input);

            fflush(stdin);

            if(input > max){
                max = input;
            }
            if(input < min){
                min = input;
            }
            total = total + input;
            i++;

        }

        printf("The number of entered numbers was %i \n", i);
        printf("The sum of the entered numbers is %f\n", total);
        total = total/i;
        printf("The average of all the numbers is %f\n", total);
        printf("The highest number entered is %i\n", max);
        printf("The lowest number entered is %i\n", min);


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've told XCode you are building a "command line application", right?

Comment: I have. A Command Line Tool, anyway, under the application tab. I learned that lesson already. =)

Comment: I fired up xcode and pasted your code and it worked for me. MacBook. Must be your environment somehow. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Does Xcode actually crash? Xcode simply reported that the program exited with a code of -1 does not mean that Xcode crashed.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. XCode itself does not crash, but the program does and no longer continues following that error. I am new to serious programming and it seems my terminology is less than accurate.

What does a code of -1 mean? I've searched the bejesus out of that and cannot find what's going on.

Comment: Does it work if you use `readInt` from my library [LCTerminal](https://github.com/Linux-cpp-lisp/LCTerminal)? I'm actually asking this for a reason because (not just self promoting ;) ) LCTerminal uses C++ I/O instead of C style.

Answer (score 0):

```
fflush(stdin);
```

You probably want

```
fflush(stdout)
```

I'm not sure what fflush() will do with an FILE* opened for input.
This may or may not be the cause of your issues.

Comment: Even without fflush() the program crashes. I also can't find this error code anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Return and Enter key have a different meaning inside Xcode. You go to the product menu and select build build for running and execute it in the terminal it will work fine.

Inside Xcode the Enter key in the numpad stops the program with a -1 return code. I am not sure whether this is bug or a feature, but I could not find the key in the keybinding for Xcode.

Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062248/xcode-lost-connection-with-error-code-1)