# What is wrong with this simple C program?

Tags: c, xcode

I am learning C, and trying out programs in Xcode. I wrote this simple program here, and was expecting the correct output.

```
//
//  main.c
//  Chap_1
//
//  Created by Manish Giri on 6/17/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Manish Giri. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.14159265

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
   // printf("Hello, World!\n");

    float radius, diameter, area, circumference;

    printf("\n Enter the diameter of the circle\n");
    scanf("%f",&diameter);

    radius=diameter/2.0;

    circumference= 2.0*PI*radius;
    area=PI*(radius)*(radius);

    printf("\n The area of the circle is: %.2f\n", area);
    printf("\n The circumference of the circle is: %.2f\n", circumference);



    return 0;
}
```

When I run it in Xcode, and try to give this input-

```
Enter the diameter of the circle
6
```

I get a pop-up from Xcode, saying- `Chap_1 exited unexpectedly` and `Lost Connection`. And then, at the bottom of the screen where the output pane is, I see this `Program ended with exit code: -1`

What am I doing wrong here? I don't find anything amiss in this program. Is it because I did not initialize my variables to zero at the very beginning? If that's the reason, why is it required?

Many thanks for your help.

**UPDATE-**

Here's a **screenshot** of this program running on Xcode(5.0.2) on an iMac

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try running this code with gcc on terminal!

Comment: [works here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d292e6459fca53f)

Comment: Works fine on [ideone](http://ideone.com/04X2UH)

Comment: ...and likewise-works on my Xcode 5.1.1 on my MBA. Are you running this as part of a ObjectiveC app hosted in an emulator or something? because "Lost Connection" sounds terribly fishy. Check your schema settings.

Comment: Ran your code in http://ideone.com. Works perfectly.

Comment: I added a screenshot of my code while running on Xcode. @WhozCraig, no I'm not using any emulator. Just the normal `Command Line Tool` from `OSX Applications`.

Comment: Works for me. You're not using the latest version of Xcode 5. I'd suggest updating to 5.1.1.

Comment: If you're looking to run small programs like this I recommend using CodeRunner: http://krillapps.com/coderunner/  It's a great tool for trying snippets of code out.  Your code runs fine using it.

Answer (score 0):

`Nothing is wrong with your program.` Probably something is wrong while you enter your input and press "Enter" key and scanf is not able to interpret it properly.
Similar known issue:
[Xcode: lost connection with Error code -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062248/xcode-lost-connection-with-error-code-1)

Can you check once after removing scanf from your program if it is giving same error.

Comment: So can you suggest a code change to overcome the potential `scanf()` issue? Without a solid coding suggestion your answer looks like a comment.